# link_to not working in a helper module (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I was trying to call link_to in a helper module

here is the code

```
 module GroupsHelper

    include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper


   def self.link_to_publish
        link_to "test"  
    end


 end
```

It returns

```
 undefined local variable or method `link_to' for GroupsHelper:Module
```

Does anyone know why? Thx

Comment: Where is this helper located?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965851/undefined-method-link-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the "self.". It's not a class method.

Assumption: GroupsHelper is in rails app's app/helpers/groups_helper.rb